# IE image spacing issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have an image above a div, and IE (7, and presumably 6) insists on putting a space between the two.  How can I get rid of that space?

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;
        border: solid 1px black" />
    <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: solid 1px green;width: 276">
        <a href="#">More...</a>&nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add "display: block" to image CSS.

IMG is display:inline by default, so you are getting a line of text that contains only image, and a div below it. The line of text has ascent that equals the height of the image and descent that equals descent of current font (which comes from the space between the image and the div). In strict mode, you will get descent even without the space.

So, another way to get rid of the gap is to set the descent to zero by specifying line-height:0 (on the parent element).

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your image markup and div markup on the same line. Strange, but this has worked for me in the past.

```
<img src="file.jpg" /><div><p>contents</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job...I wonder if there is a non-hack fix for this.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider this a "hack."

Answer (score 1):

put <br> between the two.
Explorer somehow implicitly puts a <p> in between, seeing that its unspecified.

Comment: But that forces the whitespace that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I only have IE6 on my machine, and that took the whitespace out.
<br> only takes you to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:

http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-157146.html

Comment: Don't use the "universal reset" method. Instead, always use specific reset's, like Eric Meyer's Reset.css.