# html, css - weird invisible margin below pictures

Tags: css, image, margin

I'm going bananas here, somehow below all of my images in my page there is a gap, a margin which isn't there in the code.
Even Firebug can't see it but Firefox and Safari are rendering it - EVEN WITHOUT CSS AT ALL!

This never happened to me before...!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Paranoid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" />
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="menu1">Main</li>
                <li class="menu1">System</li>
                <li class="menu1">View</li>
                <li class="menu1">Policy</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="sidebar_bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="main_content"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

body{
    background: #497e9f url(../images/bg.png) repeat-x top;
}
#container{
    width:864px;
    margin: 8px auto 0 auto;
}
#sidebar{
    /*width:139px;*/
    float: left;
}
#sidebar_bottom{
    height:10px;
    background: url(../images/sidebar_bottom_bg.png) bottom left no-repeat;
}
#sidebar #logo{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#sidebar #menu{
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 0 1px solid #cecece;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it can be due to whitespace in your HTML, as shown in <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361775/ie6-extra-padding-on-bottom/361825#361825">this other answer</a>.

Comment: Before you start your html it is better to include one of the reset.css library to your style.css

Comment: search for eric meyer reset.css

Answer (score 99):

This is actually not that uncommon. It's because the image is an inline elements so there is some space between the bottom of the image, which is placed on the base line of the text, and the bottom of the text line.

The easiest solution to this is to simply use `display:block;` to turn the image into a block element. Floating the image using `float:left;` or `float:right;` also works as that also turns it into a block element.

Adjusting properties like the `vertical-align`, `font-size` and `line-height` may also affect the distance, but it's not as robust as it doesn't really remove the effect. It might still appear in some circumstances.

Related questions:
[Unwanted spacing below images in XHTML 1.0 Strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948145/unwanted-spacing-below-images-in-xhtml-1-0-strict)
[Why have my images got extra spacing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079002/why-have-my-images-got-extra-spacing)
[IE image spacing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138211/ie-image-spacing-issue)

Comment: Setting `display: block` is still a useful advice 12 years after this answer was originally written.

Answer (score 17):

sorry to answer to this question 3 year later, but this page is in first google page and i feel responsibility ..... answer: only add **"vertical-align: top;"** to **img** tag inside **a** tag.

Comment: I have no idea on what or how but this solved my img in div 

Answer (score 9):

For me

```
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
```

on the wrapping container did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the DOCTYPE section to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

You can also check this: http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C18/12_fixes_for_the_image_spacing_in_html_emails

Answer (score -3):

Well, I got it.

it was a combination of

```
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 1;
```