# mysterious space between images in a table

Tags: html, css, layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [html, css - weird invisible margin below pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383048/html-css-weird-invisible-margin-below-pictures)

I'm working on this site: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2241201/tivoli-animation/index.html

It's just a table with a bunch of `<td><img src='' /></td>`

I've set the width and height, but I don't know where that weird white space is coming from. I also know the images are the correct size, and there doesn't seem to be any padding or margin issues here when I `inspect element` in chrome.

Answer (score 7):

It happens because your images are inline by default, so basically they are acting like text, leaving space under the baseline. You could make them `block`, with something like this:

```
table img {
    display: block;
}
```

You can read more about this here: [Images, Tables, and Mysterious Gaps - on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps)

Comment: that did it, thanks! I'll accept the answer once it lets me (5 mins from now)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the DOCTYPE section to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

You can also check this:
http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C18/12_fixes_for_the_image_spacing_in_html_emails

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to try and teach you about proper html web design, but the table entity was not meant to be used for page organization like you are using it.
Look into these slides to learn about proper floating/positioning, page sections, and the html box model.

http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12su/lectures/slides/lecture05-float.shtml#