# Div won't auto size completely with auto height and inner Image

Tags: html, css, resize, height

I have a big absolute div that holds a smaller relative div.  The smaller div wraps an Image (png) and auto sizes with height:auto.  All works fine.  But on one particular site, I get 5px of extra spacing at the bottom of the smaller div after the resize, like it over calculated the height needed?  I assume I'm somehow inheriting something from the site that is impacting my resize and div container.

I reworked everything, clear floats, overflow, alternate positioning, removed auto option, flow, etc, but I can't seem to get rid of that 5px extra at the bottom, and its only on that site?

My question - how do you debug your height or auto height issues, and any idea what could be causing this?

Thanx,
Chris

Comment: post some code or make a fiddle

Comment: It is almost impossible to answer your question without seeing your code. You could set up a demo on jsfiddle.net. Don't post all your code please, just the relevant parts.

Comment: Can it be related to images being inline? Something like [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083798/mysterious-space-between-images-in-a-table/12083841#12083841).

Comment: @Chris Don't forget to choose an "accepted answer"! And, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
font-size:0;
line-height:0
```

for smaller div

Example http://jsfiddle.net/U9z5K/14/

Or use

```
display:block;
```

for an image

Comment: Or use `float: left;` for the img [edited jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9z5K/15/)

Answer (score 2):

on the container div:

`line-height: 0px;` will eliminate any height increase caused by white space.

`padding: 0px;` will eliminate an padding along the inside of the container div.

on the image

`margin: 0px` will eliminate any space added around the outside of the image.

Could you point us to the site or a jsfiddle so we can get a better idea of what's going on?
As @RyanMcDonough mentioned, Chrome's Inspector is awesome. In IE, you have the IE developer toolbar. In FF you can use Firebug (which is a classic!).

Comment: Thank-you, line-height solved it.  I was using Firebug, but couldn't see it.

Comment: Yeah. line-height wouldn't show up in a firebug inspection because it's not really considered a layout property. It's one of those "gotchyas" of layout debugging

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like Chrome's Inspect Element, and have a look at the css rules that are affecting it.

You can then go through all the elements and enable/disable on the fly to see what is affecting it.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Firebug plugin for FF is more effective and friendly, imo