# little space between divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have another question on you. I decided to create something like web-fanpage of Mr.Robot. I have wanted to practice html and css + learn JS. But there is a problem I cant solve. There is space between divs. I tried many tutorials how to remove it but none of them helped. 
[image]

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background: black;
  padding: 1px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

header p {
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.barva {
  color: #B20707;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #B20707;
}

.Openbt {
cursor: pointer;
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
float:left;
color: #B20707;
font-size: 50px;
}

.menu .closebt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #B20707;
}


@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

}
.domu {
  height: auto;
}

img
{
  max-width: 100%;
}

.about {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="cs-cz">
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Yaaa boiii</title>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
      <p style="color:white "><span class="barva">ID:_ROOT:</span>Our<span class="barva">_democracy_</span>has<span class="barva">_</span><span class="barva">been</span>_hacked</p>
      <div class=Openbt>
    <span onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
      </div>
  </header>

<div  id="mySidemenu" class="menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebt" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>

<div id="main"> <!-- Veškerý kontent -->
  <div class="domu">
    <img src="obrazky/robot.jpg" width="1920" height="1000" />
  </div>
  <div class="about">

  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById('mySidemenu').style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById('header').style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById('mySidemenu').style.width = "0px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe you noticed that I had to set some width and height to the picture. How do I set it height 100% and width 100%? I tried to type it into .domu but it didnt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html, css - weird invisible margin below pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383048/html-css-weird-invisible-margin-below-pictures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions both involve changing your css;

1) You can change your body background color to match the about background color. This can be done by adding the following to your css.

```
body
{
  background: black;
}
```

2)You can use the `display: block;` style on your `img` tag.

```
    <img src="obrazky/robot.jpg" width="1920" height="1000"  style="display: block;"/>
```

Good luck